# Use Regex to split string at array keeping all words of array

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to turn a string into an array using RegExp. I have this string:

`const str = "Hello, bold(username!). How are you?"`

And I want that array:

`["Hello", "bold(", "username!", ")", ". How are you?"]`

I have this code:

```
const reg = /(bold\(|italic\(|\))/;
str.split(reg);
```

The return is correct, but when I try that one:

`const str = "Hello, bold((username!)). How are you?"`

The return is:

`["Hello", "bold(", "(username!", ")", "", ")", ". How are you?"]`

What can I do to get the result as below?

`["Hello", "bold(", "(username!)", ")", ". How are you?"]`

**EDIT**:

The array must have this structure:

`[..., "bold(", inside_text, ")", ...]`

where `inside_text` is every text inside main parentheses.

Comment: Try `const reg = /(bold\(|italic\(|\)(?!\)))/;`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew , but I just update my question

Comment: Pehaps use an alternation for 1 or 2 pairs of parenthesis `\b((?:bold|italic)\()(\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)(\))` https://regex101.com/r/zybHiW/1